# Azure Devops Pipeline + Trivy

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, trivy

We have installed the Trivy extension from the marketplace and traying to scan cloned repositories to be visualized on its Dashboard here it is our .yaml

```
trigger:
- main

jobs:
- job: Scan_Repository
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    persistCredentials: true
  - script: |
      git clone https://$(System.AccessToken)@test.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Infra/_git/test
    displayName: 'Clone test Repo'
  - task: trivy@1
    inputs:
      version: 'latest'
      severities: 'CRITICAL,HIGH,MEDIUM'
      path: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test'
      exitCode: 0 
    displayName: 'Run Trivy Scan'
  - script: |
      rm -rf $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test
    displayName: 'Clear local repository'
```

'When we run it we get the below errors

`##[error]Failed: Trivy detected problems. Publishing JSON results... ##[error]Unable to process command '`

`##vso[task.addattachment type=JSON_RESULT;name=trivy0.4340597811797098.json;]/tmp/trivy-results-0.31370319055668205.json' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)`

`##[error]Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'Cannot upload task attachment file, attachment file location is not specified or attachment file not exist on disk') Done! Finishing: Run Trivy Scan`

I've also tried to run it under docker, I can get the html file, but not the visualization on its dashboard

ref: https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy-azure-pipelines-task

Does anyone had a similar issue or can help me on solving this? I have created a issue on their git but doesn't seems to have much activity.

Thanks, regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are running it without Docker, add this to your task

```
    docker: false
```